# Excel Multiple Values for one anwer

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello looking to solve a problem in excel. Here is an example of my data: Please see attached file.[image]

I am looking to just grab One barcode to one value(Yes/No) for example if I wanted to see how many Yes answers there are its skewed because you can have multiple Yes/No values per barcode. which would count as 2 instead of just one value. I hope this makes sense. I tried a pivot table and everything because we need to set the barcode to a count distinct but I am lost on how to create a formula or something that would work. I cannot Remove multiple values because each line contains data I need since this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for countifs. =Countifs(a:a,1,b:b,"yes")

This will only count instances where the bar code is 1 and column b is yes

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNTA with UNIQUE and FILTER formulas nested. =COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,B:B="yes")))

The filter formula tells Unique to only look at rows where column B = Yes. Unique then creates an array of just unique entries. While CountA will count how many entries are in the array.

I added some extra entries to the example so it showcases it better. I colored the first instance of each unique entry blue to highlight the instances the unique formula is pulling.

[image: counta,unique,filter]